# Javascript generated ul looks different in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, youtube

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJsUM/)

I'm trying to create a playlist widget using javascript and html, it looks great on chrome, but when I test it in IE it looks static and only one row is displayed. I'm trying to figure this out, but I can't.

Please help me out.

p.s. this is the first time I do html and javascript :)

http://animaonline.com/api/yt/pls/v1/

Comment: Trick for beginners: when you ask a question, please post the relevant parts of your code. You could even set up a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is CSS, not JavaScript. Seeing code would help get a better answer though.

Comment: @bažmegakapa good idea, will do

Comment: This is more of a CSS question. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<a>` tags using `</a>`. I added the `</a>` right after the `<img>` tag which results in:

http://jsfiddle.net/HJsUM/3/

If you want to enclose the whole thing (the image, title and description) inside the `<a>` tag then you should change your `<a>` tag to a block element since you cannot enclose block elements (div and ul) inside inline elements. So the updated fiddle looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HJsUM/4/

Answer (score -1):

First of all - it's not the HTML that is not being displayed incorrectly, but your JavaScript seems to have some flaws here and there.

I think you're making things a bit more complex than necessary. There's a lot of challenges that others have already solved for you. It might be good to take a look at knockoutjs, which allows you to populate templates with an elegant JavaScript solution. Take a look at it, you might like it http://knockoutjs.com/

Good luck!

Comment: "I think you're making things a bit more complex than necessary." Any examples? I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the css.. I believe that using knockoutjs would be an overkill, I don't need mvvm for a rather so simple widget...

Comment: Well - in general, unless there's really no other way, you should try to avoid mixing up presentation elements (such as HTML code) and logics (your JavaScript). It might be interesting to read some articles about design patterns (or the MVC - Model View Controller - pattern in general) and the concepts of N-Tier application development.